# Error when downloading zip file TensorFlow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, machine-translation

I have been following this tutorial on machine translation by tensorflow: [Neural machine translation with attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention)

I wanted to use the same code on a [Japanes to English dataset](http://www.manythings.org/anki/jpn-eng.zip), but it threw the following error:

[image: Error]

When I try to download the file with my browser, it works without problems.

My code:

```py
# Download the file
path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'jpn-eng.zip', origin='http://www.manythings.org/anki/jpn-eng.zip', extract=True)

path_to_file = os.path.dirname(path_to_zip)+"/jpn-eng/jpn.txt"
```

Comment: It seems the website www.manythings.org reject the request of `tf.keras.utils.get_file` probably due to HTTP request head info is not satisfy minimum info, you can work around it by download the file first (e.g `!wget http://www.manythings.org/anki/jpn-eng.zip` and `!unzip jpn-eng.zip`) then load it

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> It seems the website [www.manythings.org](http://www.manythings.org) reject the request of
> tf.keras.utils.get_file probably due to HTTP request head info is not
> satisfy minimum info, you can work around it by download the file
> first (e.g !wget http://www.manythings.org/anki/jpn-eng.zip and !unzip
> jpn-eng.zip) then load it. (paraphrased from Mr. For Example)